# Updating two mongoose collections - receiving "Can't set header after they are sent"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a collection - requests - with two fields (photographers & users). I want to update the user with the request _id in order for me to use the .populate() method in the user dashboard and display the users request/s.

[image]

When I try to update the user collection i receive the following error message: 
[image]

[image]

Is this the best way to go, if not what is?

Cheers,

Comment: Please post all your code here instead of linking to it. Also refrain for using images as that makes it hard for us to copy and test your code.

Comment: The problem is that you send the response twice. First time in `updateUserTable` with user data and the second time in return of `requestCreate` with request data. Do you need somehow both (user & request)?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send a response twice in express. Which is precisely what you are trying to do. In your `requestCreate` function, you do:

`res.send(request)`

In the same method, you also call `updateUSerTable`, which also does

`res.send(user)`

You need to decide which response you want to send back and remove the other.